# Proper way to get page content

Tags: wordpress

I have to get specific page content (like page(12))

I used that :

```
  <?php $id=47; $post = get_page($id); echo $post->post_content;  ?>
```

Work nice execpt for compatibility with translations, it returns both French and English text

But  the loop is fine, return only the good language version

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div> <!-- .post -->
```

So the question.... HOW to get a specific page content inside the loop...

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I've answered my own question. Call `apply_filter` and there you go.

```
<?php 
$id=47; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;  
?>
```

Comment: get_page has been deprecated: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page.  Use get_post instead.

Comment: +1 Thank you! This is convenient when having wp_mail in a loop as well. 'get_the_content();' was not out putting the format. This helped me big time!

Comment: $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 

//Building email's message
$message = $content;

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

Comment: Why is apply_filters needed? Just $post->post_content seems to work the same, whats the difference please?

Comment: apply_filters is used in case there is a plugin somewhere that wants to "apply filters" to `the_content` - it's good for forwards compatibility

Comment: When I use the newer REST API it shows there are two properties `content.rendered` and `content.raw`. Is there a way to get the raw post content? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398446/how-to-get-raw-post-content-created-by-rest-api-call

Answer (score 38):

get page content by page name:

```
<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'page-name' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: also `get_page_by_path` might be useful.

Answer (score 14):

I used this:

```
<?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID); ?>
```

and this even more concise:

```
<?= get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID) ?>
```

Comment: This is great. For my instance I could just use `$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_id() );`

Answer (score 7):

A simple, fast way to get the content by id :

```
echo get_post_field('post_content', $id);
```

And if you want to get the content formatted :

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $id));
```

Works with pages, posts & custom posts.

Answer (score 7):

Just only copy and paste this code it will get your page content.

```
<?php
                $pageid = get_the_id();
                $content_post = get_post($pageid);
                $content = $content_post->post_content;
                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
                echo $content;
                ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The wp_trim_words function can limit the characters too by changing the $num_words variable. For anyone who might find useful.

```
<?php 
$id=58; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 

$customExcerpt = wp_trim_words( $content, $num_words = 26, $more = '' );
echo $customExcerpt;  
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'prev_text' >' Previous','post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
//get all pages 
the_ID();
the_title();

//if you want specific page of content then write
if(get_the_ID=='11')//make sure to use get_the_ID instead the_ID
{
echo get_the_ID();
the_title();
the_content();
}

endwhile;
```

//if you want specific page of content then write in loop

```
  if(get_the_ID=='11')//make sure to use get_the_ID instead the_ID
    {
    echo get_the_ID();
    the_title();
    the_content();
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question; `get_the_ID` gets the ID of the current post – question is looking for a *specific* page inside the loop.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help. 
Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
<? if (have_posts()):while(have_posts()): the_post(); the_content(); endwhile; endif; ?>
```