# How to get specific part of pages in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to get specific part of one page's content (Not whole content).

I tried the get_page(), but it will display the entire page.

Comment: You can use `get_the_excerpt()` in combination with `substr()`

Comment: In dashboard enable excerpt from screen option, and fill the content in excerpt and get the excerpt using  get_the_excerpt() in front end

Comment: Yeah. That's one solution. But my point is how to take one specific part (Like middle section of page.) without excerpt.

Comment: You can add a custom tag like `[mysection]my content goes here[/mysection]` and get all the content and extract content within this tag, through regular expression. And when you are displaying in singles/pages.php simply str_replace those tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to get page content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317366/proper-way-to-get-page-content)

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_the_excerpt() for get content after that print content according to requirement for that use substr() php function.